# Filtering Foliage/Clutter in an Image OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

Does anyone know a (preferably computationally efficient) technique and OpenCV implementation for detecting and removing the areas circled in red? And an algorithm for detecting less dense noise such as what is circled in blue?

[image: Labeled Image]

[image: Original Image]

Comment: As always: +1 for freehand circles!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe there is a nice way to do this, but my first thought was to [blur](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html?highlight=gaussianblur#gaussianblur) the image so that the dense areas will become lighter grey than than the less dense areas:

[image]

Then [binary threshold](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/threshold/threshold.html) it to get your mask:

[image]

Which you can invert/multiply etc. with the original:

[image]

This was done in photoshop as proof of concept, obviously some playing around with the parameters to be done, but hey, that's for you!

I'm 99.9999% sure openCV will be able to do all of this.

Comment: Ah, I had actually tried the blur idea earlier without success, but it was likely because I did not do binary thresholding. I will try this!

Comment: @SullyChen, Another useful tool to help clean up the mask could be the [erode and dilate](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/erosion_dilatation/erosion_dilatation.html) functions. But use them with caution; it's often better to maximise the utility of the blur and thresholding *first*.

Comment: What parameters did you use for the Gaussian Blur and the thresholding?

Comment: @SullyChen, I can't recall, and since it was Photoshop can't go back, but it shouldn't be hard to replicate. Test it at each step, and try to make it similar. Maybe you already know this but remember that kernals have to be odd size...